# IPython notebook does not launch after installing IPython dev version

Tags: installation, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I tried today to install the dev version of IPython, but when i run "ipython notebook --pylab=inline"
I get an empty notebook opens (no dash board, just a whit blank page) and the command line says:

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css (127.0.0.1) 0
2013-08-05 16:49:57.365 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js (127.0.0.1
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
2013-08-05 16:49:57.367 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/requirejs/require.js (127.0.0.1
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/components/requirejs/require.js (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
2013-08-05 16:49:57.371 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstra
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/components/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js (127.0.0.1) 1.00ms
2013-08-05 16:49:57.372 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js (127.0.0.1) 1.00ms
```

It might be due to the installation I did, which was by the guidance in ipython site, but still didnt go smooth. this is what i did:

1. installed python.
2. installed disutils
3. installed pip
4. installed git (from an installer)
5. cloned the ipython code using git
6. installed ipython.

I thought that was enough. but when I tried to launch the notebook it failed, telling me that pyzmq is not found. so I installed pyzmq. next launch failed as well, this time because of jinja2. so i installed it too. next i installed tornado.. and so on until i got the notebook up. but when it did, happen the mentioned in the top.

Cant figure out what went wrong. any help?

Comment: How did you perform the install in step#6?  Did it complete cleanly? Do you have any logs from that install?

Comment: no logs unfortunately, the cmd buffer was too short. I did as mentioned in the dev installation guide: "python setup.py install" from the ipython directory created in the git folder. I didnt see no error in the installation, perhaps some warnings.. I can install it again and watch for errors if needed...

Comment: Does running `git submodule init` followed by `git submodule update` help and installing again help?  Also, watch for any errors this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependencies can be installed like so

```
pip install pyzmq jinja2 tornado
```

However, an easier way to install is to

```
pip install .[notebook] # These brackets are literally there, not optional
```

As for the weirdness with static files, I've run into this problem when coding against the master branch, as there are git submodules. The current version of pip *should* be able to resolve these submodules. If yours doesn't, within the ipython directory (after you clone it) run

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

Now install IPython + IPython notebook

```
pip install .[notebook]
```

However, you could **just install IPython 1.0's release candidate directly**:

```
pip install http://archive.ipython.org/testing/1.0.0/ipython-1.0.0-rc1.tar.gz#egg=ipython-1.0.0-rc1
```

Comment: Dont know why what you suggested is not in the IPython docs. The installation tutorial really lacks.

Comment: @user1945306 - You could always make a pull request against the IPython docs to improve them! I think it will be much easier to install the latest and greatest when IPython 1.0 releases in the next week.

Answer (score 1):

Im writing an answer just to update and be able to write code (is there a better way to do that?)
I did the "init,update" steps you suggested, and received the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\ipython>pip install .
Unpacking c:\program files\git\bin\ipython
Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///c%7C%5Cprogram%20files%5Cgit%5Cbin%5Cipython

no previously-included directories found matching 'IPython\deathrow'
no previously-included directories found matching 'IPython\html\static\mathjax'
warning: no files found matching 'IPython\.git_commit_info.ini'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'docs\#*'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'docs\man\*.1.gz'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\gh-pages'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\dist'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.flc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.dircopy.log' found anywhere in distribution
Cleaning up...
```

So no success.. going to try to install the rc version now.

Comment: UPDATE: Installing the RC version succeeded. still dont know why the above doesnt work.