# iPython Notebook does not appear after upgrading to 1.0/1.1

Tags: jupyter-notebook

iPython notebook worked fine with python(x,y) installation which includes ipython 0.13.2-2. After upgrading to 1.0 and now 1.1, the notebook opens a blank page in the browser with backend messages like the following:

```
2013-09-13 18:10:04.236 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
2013-09-13 18:10:04.236 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/requirejs/require.js (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/components/requirejs/require.js (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
2013-09-13 18:10:04.252 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-u
i.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
2013-09-13 18:10:04.252 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
...
```

I first tried to install from a local git repository for python 1.0 that I copied over. Because this is a corporate machine, I am somewhat strapped on installation flexibility. I came back to the issue when 1.1 was released and attempted to install from the 1.1 zip for windows. Same result in both cases.

What do these message imply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you directly download the tar or zip auto generated by github ? If so then this is a known issue. You **cannot** install from zip/tar generated by github. Either use pip, or clone using git.

Deeper reason is that git repository has a submodule which is not zip'ed when you "download zip" and hence you do not get all the files.

And this is duplicate of many SO question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060160/ipython-notebook-does-not-launch-after-installing-ipython-dev-version/18071538#18071538).

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I am a bit strapped on this particular corporate machine - git/pip don't work through the corporate firewall. But, it is good to understand the basic problem. I will figure out something.

Comment: Just download also Ipython-component repo ad unzip it in IPython/HTML/component/ should work

Comment: Matt was correct - I was actually running from an iPython directory without the IPython/html/static/components. Once I copied in the components everything works.